# Вот что ему не так или проблемы с копированием файла

Tags: c#

Собственно, весь вопрос в заголовке

```
  private void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileToCopy = @"D:\Desktop\Новая папка\123led.png";
            string destinationDirectory = "";

            File.Copy(fileToCopy, destinationDirectory);
```

Comment: `string destinationDirectory =;` — а как это скомпилировалось?

Comment: @VladD, у меня не скомпилировалось :-)

Comment: `string destinationDirectory =;` - это невалидный код. Как с точки зрения компилятора, так и с точки зрения логики. Задайте значение этой переменной.

Comment: Какие у вас проблемы с копированием файла? Выпадают с обратной стороны?

Comment: Странные копипастинги происходят, однако...

Answer (score 3):

Открываем [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), читаем:

```
public static void Copy(
    string sourceFileName,
    string destFileName
)
```

```
destFileName:
    Type: System.String

    The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an existing file.
```

То есть имя целевого каталога указывать нельзя, можно лишь имя файла.

Попробуйте так:

```
File.Copy(fileToCopy, Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, "123led.png"));
```

---

P.S.: Ответ подразумевает, что вы исправили ошибку компиляции и указали правильный выходной каталог.

Answer (score -2):

Опечатка с пустым значением, там `""` или `string.Empty` должно быть.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, являетесь ли вы автором вопроса?